# Displaying data in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

when trying to use df.head(), it comes with the error below
import pandas  as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
print(df)
year month  sales  expenditure
0   2018   jan   6226         3808
1   2018   feb   1521         3373
2   2018   mar   1842         3965
3   2018   apr   2051         1098
4   2018   may   1728         3046
5   2018   jun   2138         2258
6   2018   jul   7479         2084
7   2018   aug   4434         2799
8   2018   sep   3615         1649
9   2018   oct   5472         1116
10  2018   nov   7224         1431
11  2018   dec   1812         3532
df.head()
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df.head()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

i have also tried using df.('sales') ##sales is the name of column
the system comes with the same error

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df.head()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: Can you format your code using code blocks? See [markdown formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That means your df is a list instead of a pandas dataframe. You may post more or your code on how you created this dataframe for us to help you debug what went wrong. Try to use the `` formatter to format your code so that its more readable.